# read from a file that is in the same folder as the .jar file

Tags: java, file, jar

Is there a way to read from a file that is in the same folder as the .jar file? I am trying to create a java program that has to read from a file when I turn in my assignment. I do not know where the file or program will be held once I turn it over so I dont think I can encode the directory of the held file. Is this possible? The problem is that i have to upload the file to a CSX hosts server which is a linux server and run it from there. If I dont put a path before the file will it just search its current folder location?

Comment: What's your context: Applet or Desktop? Can you put the file into the JAR as a resource?

Comment: Can you have your program take the path to the file as a command line argument?

Comment: Use ClassLoader.findResource to find your class.  Decode the resulting URL to figure out where it is.

Comment: Why not answer the question in the answer box?

Comment: (Of course, findResource is protected, so it takes some cleverness.)

Comment: Will the file you are reading change, or will it always be the same?

Comment: The file will have the same file name but the contents will be different which I have accounted for in the code

Comment: Ok, so you are uploading a file to a server.  How are you running the jar?  Will the file always be in the same folder as the jar?

Comment: yes it will always be the same folder as the jar and I run the file with linux commands

Comment: Ok, that should be easy enough, I'll update my answer

Comment: (Though if you're lucky your class was loaded by a subclass of URLClassLoader, and findResource is public for that class.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**As noted in the comments, this works only if you run the command from the directory the jar is in.**

*(In the context of a desktop application)*
To access a file that's in the current directory of the `jar`, your `path` to the file should be preceded by a dot. Example:

```
String path = "./properties.txt";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
// Read the file contents...
```

In this example, there is a text file called `properties.txt` in the same directory as the `jar`.
This file will be read by the program contained in the `jar`.
**Edit:** you said the filename would not change, and this answer applies given that you know the name beforehand, of course, should you prefer to hardcode it.

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than mine however it does not handle all the cases. Sometimes one's current directory (the . ) is not the same as the dir containing the application jar. Assuming your jar is called app.jar and is in a dir named target; if the grader were to type "java -jar app.jar" from within the target dir then your solution will work. However if the grader were to run the java command one level outside the app dir e.g. "java -jar ./target/app.jar" then your solution would look for the input file outside of the target dir and thus would not find it.

Comment: I was convinced that the dot would always map to the current location of the running jar. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Adding './' to the front of a filename accomplishes precisely nothing. 'Current directory of the JAR' isn't the same thing as 'same folder as the .jar'. -1

Comment: Thank you for the ./ ... It will in fact accomplish the reading of a file... That will work in my command prompt. Thanks again

Comment: For me it seems like working only while running .jar file from terminal. If I'm trying to open it with Java Runtime it does not work. When I wanted to see absolute path of "." file it returns my home folder location. 
What worked for me was creating String which stores path to parent folder of .jar file: String filesDirectory = (new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent() + "/").replace("%20", " "); . Anyway I would appreciate some prettier solution.

Comment: @Bain It will in fact accomplish precisely nothing compared to removing it.

Comment: Need to emphasize @Darwyn comment. This will only work if the command is run at JAR directory.

Comment: And if we need to read all the .json file(names are not fixed) from a folder which is at same level as jar file?

Comment: @JoshuaH No, it will only work if the file and the JAR are both in the current woring directory. Command prompt has nothing to do with it. This answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 26):

You can get the location of the JAR file containing any specific class via:

```
URL url = thisClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

From there it is easy to relativize a URL to the desired file.

Answer (score 4):

if the input filename can be hardcoded and you know that it will always reside in the same directory as the jar containing your code then this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // Determine where the input file is; assuming it's in the same directory as the jar
        String fileName = "input.txt";
        File jarFile = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        String inputFilePath = jarFile.getParent() + File.separator + fileName;         
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFilePath));

        try {

            // Read in the contents of the input file in a single gulp
            FileChannel fc = inStream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,
                    fc.size());

            // Do something with the read in data
            System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb)
                    .toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inStream.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: *"this should work:"*  It would not work in an applet or any application launched using JWS, probably also not a servlet.  Even Sun was telling us long ago WTE, "don't try to locate the executable - it is none of the apps. business".

Comment: True it will fail in an applet, or when launched by java web start, or when running in an application server (e.g. OSGi, IBM WebSphere, Oracle WebLogics, etc). But it will work as a normal desktop java application.

Comment: Desktop app.? *"a linux server and run it from there"*  Doesn't seem like the desktop to me.

Answer (score 2):

@kcpr - Thanks for the solutions provided. Below one worked for me.

```
private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "lib"+ File.separator + "Config.properties";

static {
    File jarFile = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
    String inputFilePath = jarFile.getParent() + File.separator + CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION; 
    propConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration(new File(inputFilePath));
    propConfig.load();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `toURI()`?  The `getLocation()` returns a URL object which seems to include the same path...  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

To make it 'self-contained', put the resource *inside* the Jar.   It then becomes a (read only) [embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for which we can obtain an URL using something along the lines of:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you get a clean directory path to your jar file (Based on EJP's answer):

```
URL url = IssueInfoController.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String urlString = url.toString();
int firstSlash =  urlString.indexOf("/");
int targetSlash = urlString.lastIndexOf("/", urlString.length() - 2) + 1;

return urlString.substring(firstSlash, targetSlash) + YOUR_FILE;
```

Comment: Should use `URL.getPath()` instead of all this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think your best solution would be to pass in the absolute path of the uploaded file into the jar.

You can pass the path into the jar as a command line argument.  Since the path and file name do not change, and you are runing it from linux, you could create a .sh script to run it.

```
#!/bin/bash    
java -jar myjar.jar /path/to/file/filename.txt
```

This also frees you from hardcoding in a file path, or file name into the jar.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Read it again. He doesn't know where the file will be.

Comment: Truth is not a function of time.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestClassLoaderAccess {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        TestClassLoaderAccess me = new TestClassLoaderAccess();
        ClassLoader myLoader = me.getClass().getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(myLoader.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());
        java.net.URLClassLoader myUrlLoader = (java.net.URLClassLoader) myLoader;
        java.net.URL resource = myUrlLoader.findResource("TestClassLoaderAccess.class");
        System.out.println(resource.toString());
    }
}
```

Running it:

```
C:\JavaTools>javac TestClassLoaderAccess.java

C:\JavaTools>java TestClassLoaderAccess
java.net.URLClassLoader
file:/C:/JavaTools/TestClassLoaderAccess.class

C:\JavaTools>
```

(The first println is just to prove that the class loader is a subclass of URLClassLoader.)

Comment: This finds a resource *inside* the JAR. It only works here because there is no JAR at all. Not what was asked for. Not an answer.